# Enabling server side includes (SSI) in Ubuntu 16.04 is not working

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2.4, html5

I have an html page with SSI and I was trying for enabling SSI in my apache (V 2.4.18) running on Ubuntu 16.04. As per the offical documentation, I tried editing /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and now included following directives,

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml 
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it was not successful. Also, I tried the direction from [here](https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/apache2-ssi-installation/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200522/apache-not-processing-basic-ssi?rq=1) and a few similar posts. Unfortunately, it was also failed to enable SSI. Anyone can direct me to solve this issue?

Note: First, I posted it in Server fault ([post](https://serverfault.com/questions/885094/how-to-enable-ssi-in-ubuntu-16-04)), but couldn't get a response and I decided to AskUbuntu.

Comment: On 16.04 you should not need the  `AddType` line, as it should already be in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf`. However, you do need to add `Includes` to your `Options` line.

Comment: Now it works!! Thanks for your time to look into the problem

Answer (score 3):

This is how i did it using server side includes

1. Include your html page inside body:

   ```
   <!--#include virtual="mypage.shtml"-->
   ```
2. Enable the Include and Include.load module

   ```
   sudo a2enmod include
   sudo a2enmod include.load
   ```
3. Edit: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

   Paste below lines inside VirtualHost Tag:

   ```
   AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php
   ```
4. Edit your `.htaccess`:
   Paste below line:

   ```
   Options +Includes
   ```
5. Restart your apache by typing:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Note:
I am using php with ubuntu